# Proof that $\frac{2\times2\times2\times4\times4\cdots(2n)\times(2n)}{3\times3\times5\times5\cdots(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}$ converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-integrals

I defined
$$S_{2n}=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-3)\cdots (2n-1) }{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n-2)\cdot (2n)}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$S_{2n+1}=\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n-2)\cdots (2n) }{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)\cdot (2n+1)},$$
where
$$S_n=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\sin x)^n\, dx.$$
I proved that $S_n=\left( \frac{n-1}{n}\right) S_{n-2}$ and that $S_{n}\geq S_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now, I need that
$$W_n=\frac{2\times2\times2\times4\times4\cdots(2n)\times(2n)}{3\times3\times5\times5\cdots(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}=\frac{S_{2n+1}}{S_{2n}}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}$$
converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I tried to prove that
$$\frac{S_{2n+1}}{S_{2n}}=\frac{2\times2\times2\times4\times4\cdots(2n)\times(2n)}{3\times3\times5\times5\cdots(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}\cdot\frac{2}{\pi}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1,$$
but I did not succeed.

Comment: You define $S_{2n}$ and $S_{2n+1}$, but then you define $S_n$ to be something else? Also, more line breaks will make it a lot easier to understand what you want to say.

Comment: You can look for *Wallis product* . E.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) , it's a proof there.

Comment: You *define* $S_n$ using the integral and then you *compute* that $S_{2n} = \ldots$ etc. You got it the other way around.

Comment: thanks @user90369

Comment: You are welcome. ;)